# PHP/ CSS I am trying to lower the font weight of this H3 and nothing seems to work

Tags: css

Site is here:

http://www.hrsrevcycle.com/testing/

See the scrolling news feed in the upper right. I am trying to lower the font-weight on the red h3 headers on feed. I have successfully applied:

```
.spe_link a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 100 !important;
}
```

But the news headers (red h3s) still appear bold. Is the plugin overriding the styles, or is it because they are h3s and cant be lowered in weight? I have tried fixing this for a while, any tips are much appreciated!

Comment: There actually are no `H3` tags. Probably won't help, but the javascript scrolling keeps me from inspecting the source for longer than a second. So this is as much as I can contribute.

Comment: It looks like your font "oxygen" has no lighter font weights. You'll have to use a different font to get a lighter font weight. (if you make it `font-family: sans-serif;` you'll notice it get lighter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only loading in the `700` thickness version of the oxygen font.

You just need to amend the call for the fonts in your head and you should be fine. The next thickness down for the oxygen font is `400`.

Something like this:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Oxygen:400:700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Nice one, I wasn't familiar with the Oxygen font, knew the weight wasn't supported though.

Answer (score 0):

I think it just means that your font does not support this weight.

When you used tools like Typekit, you always have to choose which weights you want to embed, so I guess that means that you cannot apply any weight to any font!

Try to find the `Light` or `Thin` version of your font.